# Prevent .bashrc from running when starting a new xterm instance

Tags: xterm, bashrc

I am running CentOS 6.6, and occasionally when I spawn a new xterm window, I don't want the xterm instance to source .bashrc.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What determines whether you want `.bashrc` to run or not? Is it only `.bashrc` that you want to inhibit, or `/etc/bash.bashrc` also? Check the `--bashrc` start-up option.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.bashrc` is not read by `xterm`; it is read by the `bash` that `xterm` runs if you don't supply a command with `-e`.  You can tell Bash not to read `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` by giving it the `--norc` option:

```
xterm -e bash --norc
```

You may, of course, want to source `/etc/bash.bashrc` but not `~/.bashrc`; I suggest you simply do that from within your new shell:

```
. /etc/bash.bashrc
```

but you may instead tell Bash to use that as your one and only initialization file:

```
xterm -e bash --rcfile /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Full details of those Bash options are of course in the man page.